# How do I render jinja2 output to a file in Python instead of a Browser

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I have a jinja2 template (.html file) that I want to render (replace the tokens with values from my py file).  Instead of sending the rendered result to a browser, however, I want to write it to a new .html file.  I would imagine the solution would also be similar for a django template.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 167):

How about something like this?

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates'))
template = env.get_template('test.html')
output_from_parsed_template = template.render(foo='Hello World!')
print(output_from_parsed_template)

# to save the results
with open("my_new_file.html", "w") as fh:
    fh.write(output_from_parsed_template)
```

**test.html**

```
<h1>{{ foo }}</h1>
```

**output**

```
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
```

If you are using a framework, such as Flask, then you could do this at the bottom of your view, before you return.

```
output_from_parsed_template = render_template('test.html', foo="Hello World!")
with open("some_new_file.html", "wb") as f:
    f.write(output_from_parsed_template)
return output_from_parsed_template
```

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response.
If I am understanding correctly, then to your first snippit:
  from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
  env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates'))
  template = env.get_template('test.html')
  output_from_parsed_template = template.render(foo='Hello World!')
  print output_from_parsed_template

I could replace the print line with some kind of a file write line.  Is that correct?  What might such a line to write to a file look like?

Re. Flask, this is a small part of a larger app, so I don't know if I would be able to use a framework.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I finally had a chance to try this out.  Initially I got an error "No such file or directory: 'my_new_file.html'".  Apparently the file already has to exist.  I then copied the template file and renamed it to 'my_new_file.html'.  Now I get an error: IOError: File not open for writing.  Could this be because I am developing in Google App Engine?

Comment: @BillG. No, it was an error on my part.  Try the change above: changed `rb` to `wb`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I changed the rb to wb and now I get the following error: IOError: invalid mode: wb

Comment: There's a missing `)` on the end of the first line in the bottom code section.
I was trying to add it, but SO requires edits to be >6 characters (stupid limitation)..

Comment: @egeland Ah, indeed there is.  Fixed.  Thanks for pointing it out.  It's only been like that for 2.5 years!  :-)

Answer (score 65):

You can dump a template stream to file as follows:

```
Template('Hello {{ name }}!').stream(name='foo').dump('hello.html')
```

Ref: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.9.x/api/#jinja2.environment.TemplateStream.dump

Answer (score 11):

So after you've loaded the template, you call render and then write the output to a file. The 'with' statement is a context manager. Inside the indentation you have an open file like object called 'f'.

```
template = jinja_environment.get_template('CommentCreate.html')     
output = template.render(template_values)) 

with open('my_new_html_file.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(output)
```

Comment: So, would this look something like:
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
        jinja_environment = \
            jinja2.Environment(autoescape=False, loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(TEMPLATE_DIR))

        template = jinja_environment.get_template('CommentCreate.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))
with open('my_new_html_file.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(response.content)

where template_values where already populated.

Please correct as needed.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I finally had a chance to try this out.  Initially I got an error "No such file or directory: 'my_new_file.html'".  Apparently the file already has to exist.  I then copied the template file and renamed it to 'my_new_file.html'.  Now I get an error: IOError: File not open for writing.  Could this be because I am developing in Google App Engine?